Laravel queue/jobs is looking at the wrong database when job fails to record it
the queue can read the jobs table and find the right database.
However, when the job fails, it defaults to the connection database.sqlite, which is wrong.
I am getting this error --  database file at path [*******\database\database.sqlite] does not exist. Ensure this is an absolute path to the database. (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "failed_jobs" (......
.env
QUEUE_CONNECTION=queue_database
DB_QUEUE_CONNECTION="systems"
DB_QUEUE_TABLE="jobs"
DB_QUEUE="default"
DB_QUEUE_RETRY_AFTER="120"

queue.php
**Notice here my database111 is default if no value in the .env file, yet the error message says database.sqlite do not understand where that is coming from.
***I have run the config:clear and cache:clear commands


'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database111'),
'connections' => [
    'queue_database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'connection' => env('DB_QUEUE_CONNECTION'),
        'table' => env('DB_QUEUE_TABLE', 'jobs'),
        'queue' => env('DB_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => (int) env('DB_QUEUE_RETRY_AFTER', 90),
        'after_commit' => false,
    ],
],

database.php
'connections' => [
    'systems' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('dbs\systems.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => true,
        'busy_timeout' => null,
        'journal_mode' => null,
        'synchronous' => null,
    ],
],

